# How to write unit test case for react msal library private router in reactjs

Tags: react-router-dom, react-testing-library, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, msal-react

I am trying to write the unit test case for the private route we created, using `@azure/msal-react`

below is the code for the private route

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
    AuthenticatedTemplate,
    UnauthenticatedTemplate,
} from '@azure/msal-react';

export const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
    const {
        component: Component,
        ...restProps
    } = props;

    if (!Component) return null;
    return (
        <Route
            exact
            {...restProps}
            render={(routeRenderProps) => (
                <>
                    <AuthenticatedTemplate>
                        <Component
                            {...routeRenderProps}
                            {...restProps}
                        />
                    </AuthenticatedTemplate>
                    <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
                        <Redirect
                            to={{
                                pathname: '/auth/signin',
                                state: { from: routeRenderProps.location },
                            }}
                        />
                    </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
                </>
            )}
        />
    );
};
```

below is the unit test case I wrote using react testing library

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MsalAuthenticationTemplate } from '@azure/msal-react';
import { PrivateRoute } from '../privateRoute';

describe('PrivateRoute', () => {
  test('renders the component when the user is authenticated', () => {
    const Component = () => <div>My Component</div>;
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
        <MsalAuthenticationTemplate>
          <PrivateRoute
            path="/"
            component={Component}
          />
        </MsalAuthenticationTemplate>
      </MemoryRouter>,
    );

    const componentElement = screen.getByText('My Component');
    expect(componentElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

but this test case doesn't work, as it was not able to find the component.

pls refer to the attached image,

[image]

Could please help me to resolve this issue?

another test case I tried like this below, here I am setting an authentication status by passing a mockClient to the msal provider

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MsalProvider } from '@azure/msal-react';
import { PrivateRoute } from '../privateRoute';

describe('PrivateRoute', () => {
  test('renders the component when the user is authenticated', () => {
    const Component = () => <div>My Component</div>;

    // Create an instance of MsalProvider with a mocked instance
    const mockClient = {
      getAllAccounts: jest.fn(() => [{ name: 'Test User' }]),
    };
    render(
      <MsalProvider instance={mockClient}>
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
          <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Component} />
        </MemoryRouter>
      </MsalProvider>,
    );

    const componentElement = screen.getByText('My Component');
    expect(componentElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

});
```

but it shows the below error message

[image]

Comment: How does your unit test code set the authentication status of the conditions you want to exercise the `PrivateRoute` component with?

Comment: I have updated my answer, where I am setting an authentication status by passing a mockClient to the msal provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way to set the authentication status

Please find the below code for it. `msal-react-tester` this library helps to set the authentication status.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MsalProvider } from '@azure/msal-react';
import { MsalReactTester } from 'msal-react-tester';
import { PrivateRoute } from '../privateRoute';

describe('PrivateRoute', () => {
    let msalTester;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        // new instance of msal tester for each test:
        msalTester = new MsalReactTester();

        // Ask msal-react-tester to handle and mock all msal-react processes:
        await msalTester.spyMsal();
    });

    afterEach(async () => {
        // reset msal-react-tester
        await msalTester.resetSpyMsal();
    });

    test('renders the component when the user is authenticated', async () => {
        const Component = () => <div>My Component</div>;

        // Set the user as logged in
        await msalTester.isLogged();

        render(
            <MsalProvider instance={msalTester.client}>
                <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
                    <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Component} />
                </MemoryRouter>
            </MsalProvider>,
        );

        // Wait for the authentication redirect to resolve
        await msalTester.waitForRedirect();

        const componentElement = screen.getByText('My Component');
        expect(componentElement).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
       
});
```